# How to break out of xsl:for-each loop in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I understand that XSLT doesn't allow one to directly break out of a `xsl:for-each` loop, but there must be an easy way to add more conditions to achieve it. I've seen much online on the same context but unable to proceed further.

I want to iterate through a set of XML tags and come out of the iteration on finding a value in one XML tag and use that value in another `xsl:template`. For example,

```
<xsl:template name="categoryCheckTemplate">
 <xsl:for-each select="TEST/ABC/DEF/GHI/Row">
    <xsl:variable name="category">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="JKL/Category">
                <xsl:value-of select="JKL/Category"/>                           
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="MNO/Category">
                <xsl:value-of select="MNO/Category"/>                           
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="(contains($category,'123'))">
            <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>    
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to use the `'true'` value of this template in another template but don't want to iterate it all the way. Anytime it is true, I need to come out of the iteration.

**XML Input**

```
<xml>
    <TEST>
        <ABC>
            <DEF>
                <GHI>
                    <Row>
                        <JKL>
                            <Category>123</Category>
                        </JKL>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <JKL>
                            <Category>456</Category>
                        </JKL>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <JKL>
                            <Category>789</Category>
                        </JKL>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <JKL>
                            <Category>012</Category>
                        </JKL>
                    </Row>
                </GHI>
            </DEF>
        </ABC>
    </TEST>
</xml>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<item>
    <cat>123</cat>
</item>
```

Can anyone help on this XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You're thinking too procedurally.**  You don't need to break; you don't even need to loop.

**Your entire procedure can *and should* be reduced to a single XPath expression:**

```
string(contains(TEST/ABC/DEF/GHI/Row/*[self::JKL or self::MNO]/Category, '123'))
```

That's it.  No loop.  No break. Just tests against the input XML and an optional conversion to string (which may or may not be necessary in your actual context).

---

### Update after OP added input XML and desired output XML:

This XSLT,

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <item>
      <xsl:if test="/xml/TEST/ABC/DEF/GHI/Row/
                    *[self::JKL or self::MNO]/Category = 123">
        <cat>123</cat>
      </xsl:if>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce the requested output XML,

```
<item>
   <cat>123</cat>
</item>
```

if the original procedurally specified condition is true<sup>1</sup>, or this output XML,

```
<item/>
```

otherwise.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I took the liberty of also switching from a string contains test to a string value equality test, which is more likely what's desired here (else "1234" et al would also satisfy the test).</sub>

Comment: Does "TEST/ABC/DEF/GHI/Row/*[self::JKL or self::MNO]/Category" work directly?

Comment: It matched your original XSLT.  Now that you've added input XML and desired output XML, I can build out the answer if you'd like.  You should say what output you'd like in the case that there is no such `Category` element in the input containing `123`.

Comment: Answer updated to show full XSLT using the described principle that you do not need a break statement or even a loop.

Comment: The one case where you do need something like this is when the condition is cumulative, e.g. break after the sum of the sizes of the paragraphs processed exceeds some threshold. In that case you can use the XSLT 3.0 xsl:iterate instruction, or in earlier versions of the spec you can use a recursive function or template instead of xsl:for-each.

Comment: Got it and it's working as expected. Thanks a lot all :)