# Break statement in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm looking for kind of a break statement in XSLT.

Below is my input:

```
     <ListOfCrnEstimates>
               <CrnEstimates>
                <CRNEstimatePackage>Mobile Claims</CRNEstimatePackage>
                <CRNEstimateAssignStatus>Pending</CRNEstimateAssignStatus>
                          </CrnEstimates>
                          <CrnEstimates>
                             <CRNEstimatePackage>Adjuster</CRNEstimatePackage>                  
                             <CRNEstimateAssignStatus>Pending1</CRNEstimateAssignStatus>
                          </CrnEstimates>
                         <CrnEstimates>
                             <CRNEstimatePackage>Inside Adjuster</CRNEstimatePackage>                   
                             <CRNEstimateAssignStatus>Moved to Mobile Claims</CRNEstimateAssignStatus>
                          </CrnEstimates>
                          <CrnEstimates>
                        <CRNEstimatePackage>Mobile Claims</CRNEstimatePackage> 
<CRNEstimateAssignStatus>Completed</CRNEstimateAssignStatus>                                    <CRNEstimateAssignStatus>Completed</CRNEstimateAssignStatus>
                          </CrnEstimates>               
        </ListOfCrnEstimates>
```

Note: `CRNEstimateAssignStatus` values may differ...

I have to check for `CRNEstimatePackage = Mobile Claims` and have to create a request to backend with retaining that particular `<CrnEstimates>` and remove other `<CrnEstimates>`.

For the above request, I should generate 2 backend requests as below:

### Output1:

```
 <ListOfCrnEstimates>
                  <CrnEstimates>
                     <CRNEstimatePackage>Mobile Claims</CRNEstimatePackage>                    
                     <CRNEstimateAssignStatus>Pending</CRNEstimateAssignStatus>
                  </CrnEstimates>                
    </ListOfCrnEstimates>
```

### Output2:

```
<ListOfCrnEstimates>
                  <CrnEstimates>
                     <CRNEstimatePackage>Mobile Claims</CRNEstimatePackage>                    
                    <CRNEstimateAssignStatus>Completed</CRNEstimateAssignStatus>
                  </CrnEstimates>                
         </ListOfCrnEstimates>
```

Currently I'm using below xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" /> 
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> 
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="*:CrnEstimates[descendant::*:CRNEstimatePackage[. != 'Mobile Claims']]"/>      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and Im getting below response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListOfCrnEstimates>
   <CrnEstimates>
      <CRNEstimatePackage>Mobile Claims</CRNEstimatePackage>
      <CRNEstimateAssignStatus>Pending</CRNEstimateAssignStatus>
   </CrnEstimates>
   <CrnEstimates>
      <CRNEstimatePackage>Mobile Claims</CRNEstimatePackage>
      <CRNEstimateAssignStatus>Completed</CRNEstimateAssignStatus>
   </CrnEstimates>
</ListOfCrnEstimates>
```

Comment: You haven't provided a [mcve]. Without it and a clear question it's difficult to estimate what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break out of xsl:for-each loop in XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583912/how-to-break-out-of-xslfor-each-loop-in-xslt)

Comment: Scrolling to the right reveals that in your poorly-formatted XML, the last `CRNEstimateAssignStatus` element appears twice. Is this intended?

Comment: You haven't explained what you think the semantics of your desired break statement would be, or why you think such a statement would be helpful to solving your problem. You might as well tell us that you would like some magic fairy dust.

Answer (score 0):

As i think you want to do nothing when `CRNEstimatePackage[. != 'Mobile Claims']` that what it is dropping all `CrnEstimates` that descendant//CRNEstimatePackage values are not 'Mobile Claims'.